# Why does `keyof object` return a never type?

Tags: typescript

Why does `keyof object` return a never type?

I think the right thing should be `number | string | symbol`

```
type T = keyof object // never
```

Comment: For the same reason `keyof {}` returns `never`, the type you're looking at doesn't have any keys in it. Similarly `keyof { foo: string }` returns `"foo"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `object` does not have any keys in it. Therefore you don't receive the union you expect but simply the type `never` instead.

The `object` type almost represents the same thing as `{}`. The difference ist that `object` only accepts non-primitives while `{}` accepts anything that isn't `null` or `undefined`. (Thanks to @jcalz in the comments). Looking at `{}` it seems very obvious that there are no keys on the type. Since there are no keys to map TypeScript simply returns the type `never`.

Note that `{}` is a type in your case and not a value. You cannot/don't have to do something like

```
type T = typeof {};
             // ~ --> Identifier expected.ts(1003)
```

Comment: "The `object` type represents the same thing as `{}`".  No, the `object` type only accepts non-primitives, while `{}` accepts anything that isn't `null` or `undefined`.  So `const x: object = ""` is an error, while `const x: {} = ""` is not.

Comment: It may be a good idea to clarify that "the `object` type has no keys" doesn't mean "a value of the `object` type has no properties", but instead "if all you know about a value is that it has type `object`, then you don't know any of its properties".  A value of type `object` may have all sorts of keys.  But the `keyof` type operator only returns the union of key types known to be usable on every member of the type.